# how to backup and restore mysql database from remoteclient to server and vice versa using java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have tried to backup and restore mysql database from localhost using like this command:

```
//for backup command :
String cmd ="C:\\DreamSoft\\DreamSoftSchoolSoftware\\src\\mysqlexe\\mysqldump.exe -uroot -proot  school -r "+path;



//for restore command:
String[] command = new String[]{"C:\\DreamSoft\\DreamSoftSchoolSoftware\\src\\mysqlexebut now
```

Now , I want to backup and restore totally from remote client to db server.

If my question don't have enough requirement please suggest me.

Thanks all